# Use Basic4Android signature key with .keystore extension For flutter .jks

Tags: flutter, basic4android

I want to use the signature key made with [Basic4Android](https://www.b4x.com/b4a.html) for the [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/)
But when installing the update on the old version, it says that the program was not installed
Is there a way?